# Java Calendar setTimeZone method behaviour

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

When I run the code below on windows with java6 it prints the following output.

```
private static SimpleDateFormat timeZoneFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String format = "yyyyMMdd";

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse("20140330");
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(date1);

        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("20140401");

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(date2);
        calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        calendar2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        System.out.println(timeZoneFormatter.format(calendar1.getTime()));
        System.out.println(timeZoneFormatter.format(calendar2.getTime()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
+0200
+0300
```

As far as I see no matter what timezone I set on calendar objects it takes defaulttimezone info on SimpleDateFormat object. Am I missing something here ? If this is normal behaviour, in which situation we should use Calendar.setTimezone() method?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why time zone setting is not effective in your example is that: instead of applying
`setTimeZone` to the calendar object, one should apply `setTimeZone` to the `timeZoneFormatter` object.

**Please see my executable example code below. This code will demonstrate the usage and effects of time zone.**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneTEST {
    private static SimpleDateFormat timeZoneFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String timezone_GMT = "GMT";
            String timezone_NYC = "America/New_York";
            long currentLongTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Effect of time zone when displaying time as hhmm
            System.out.format("Current time(HHMM) in [%s] time zone is [%d]\n", timezone_GMT, getCurrentTime(currentLongTime, timezone_GMT));
            System.out.format("Current time(HHMM) in [%s] time zone is [%d]\n", timezone_NYC, getCurrentTime(currentLongTime, timezone_NYC));

            // Effect of time zone when displaying the formatted string representation of time
            System.out.format("Current time(String representation) in [%s] time zone is [%s]\n", timezone_GMT, fmtDateWithTZ(currentLongTime,timezone_GMT));
            System.out.format("Current time(String representation) in [%s] time zone is [%s]\n", timezone_NYC, fmtDateWithTZ(currentLongTime,timezone_NYC));
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static int getCurrentTime(long longTime, String timeZone){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(longTime);
        int hhmm = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 100 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return hhmm;    
    }

    public static String fmtDateWithTZ( long ms, String timeZone) {
        timeZoneFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        return timeZoneFormatter.format( new Date( ms) );
    } 
}
```

After running the code, one should see the following outputs (actual time showing will be the current time):

> Current time(HHMM) in [GMT] time zone is [945]
>
> Current time(HHMM) in [America/New_York] time zone is [545]
>
> Current time(String representation) in [GMT] time zone is [2014-09-09 09:45:42 GMT]
>
> Current time(String representation) in [America/New_York] time zone is [2014-09-09 05:45:42 EDT]

**A side note**, by applying different time zone, the same time component can be displayed differently according to the time zone specified. This is to be distinguished from the long time representation of time, which measures the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970. This quantity is time zone neutral, whose value will not change with time zone.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Actually formatter part is coming from api(I can not change it) and I am supposed to send a Calendar object. I was trying to find a way to set timezone.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the timeZoneFormatter is not formatting calendar1's timezone, but rather the timezone of an anonymous Date that was returned by calendar1.getTime(). It is this Date object that is being formatted. As a Date doesn't have a timezone, it is formatted according to the timezone of the formatter, which in this case is the default timezone.